# Difference in writing Spark applications

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a difference in performance if you write Spark applications via method chains vs SparkSQL? I know writing codes using methods is more flexible but I'm not sure about the performance between the two.

Example:

```
spark.select().filter().etc....
```

versus

```
spark.sql("<insert query here>")
```

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: The performance should be the same, assuming you're sure the methods are generating the same sql you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in performance between

```
df.select($"some_col").filter($"filter_col" === "somevalue")
```

and

```
spark.sql("select some_col from some_table where filter_col = 'somevalue'")
```

The spark plan that gets generated for both the cases is the same. Out of these, which to choose is completely subjective.

You can check the spark plan by running:

```
df.queryExecution.sparkPlan
```

Further reads on Spark plan :

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-optimized-logical-plan-in-spark
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html